# escape \\\ to \ in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > buffer = ''

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > i = "buffer << \\\"[@user_id,@account_id]\\\""
=> "buffer << \\\"[@user_id,@account_id]\\\"" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > eval i
SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
buffer << \"[@user_id,@account_id]\"
          ^
(eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file
   from (irb):25:in `eval'

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > j = "buffer << \"[@user_id,@account_id]\""
=> "buffer << \"[@user_id,@account_id]\"" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 > eval j
=> "[@user_id,@account_id]"
```

How do I convert i into j?

or

How to convert "buffer << \\"[@user_id,@account_id]\\"" into "buffer << \"[@user_id,@account_id]\" ?

Comment: Try simplifying the code you have until you have the least amount of code showing your problem.

Comment: Can you clarify the query? Because you already got the solution that for escaping " only one \ is sufficient.

Comment: how to convert "buffer << \\\"[@user_id,@account_id]\\\"" into "buffer << \"[@user_id,@account_id]\" ?

Comment: The title and the `eval` tag is inappropriate

Comment: title renamed and `eval` tag dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question "how do i convert i into j":

```
i.gsub(/\\/, '')
```

However, it very much looks as if the question is wrong and should rather be "how to I rewrite the surrounding code in order not having to do stuff like this in the first place".